# Admob app status red even after pressing ads (Iphone)

Tags: iphone, admob, ads

I have added Admob ads to my Iphone app.
The app is in the AppStore and the ads are showing in my app.
I've tried to press and ad (and I know other people pressed as well), however, the status in the Admob site remains red.
(In my Android app it is indeed green).

Any thoughts why? Should I have activated it in some way?

Thanks,
Inbar

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I figurd it out - I thought the ad code is the same for Android and Iphone, but it turns out they are not.. I copied the Iphone key to the app and re submited to AppStore.
I hope this will fix the problem